# Adding an int member to a C struct causes a segfault

Tags: c, struct, malloc, segmentation-fault

I'm still learning C, and have started using it to generate images. I can't figure out why one of my programs is segfaulting. Here's the source code, cut down to 40 lines:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct color {
        unsigned char r, g, b;
};
struct image {
        int w, h/*, o*/;
        struct color **data;
};
int main() {
        // Declarations
        int x, y;
        struct color *black;
        struct image *img;
        // Set up color black
        black = (struct color *) malloc(sizeof(struct color *));
        black->r = 0;
        black->g = 0;
        black->b = 0;
        // Set up image img
        img = (struct image *) malloc(sizeof(struct image *));
        img->w = 1;
        img->h = 1;
        /*img->o = 0;*/
        img->data = (struct color **) malloc(img->h * sizeof(struct color *));
        for (y = 0; y < img->h; y++) {
                img->data[y] = (struct color *) malloc(img->w * sizeof(struct color));
        }
        // Fill in img with black
        for (x = 0; x < img->w; x++) {
                for (y = 0; y < img->h; y++) {
                        img->data[y][x].r = black->r;
                        img->data[y][x].g = black->g;
                        img->data[y][x].b = black->b;
                }
        }
        // Free black
        free(black);
        // Free img
        for (y = 0; y < img->h; y++)
                free(img->data[y]);
        free(img->data); // Segfaults
        free(img); // Also segfaults
        return 0;
}
```

It compiles and runs fine (using gcc on Ubuntu and on Vista with Cygwin), but uncommenting the two lines dealing with img->o breaks it. I have a feeling it's related to [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433700/segfault-from-adding-a-variable), but I'm malloc'ing everything that needs to be malloc'ed (I think). Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 21):

There is a bug in your malloc statements.  You are mallocing a pointer and not a struct.  This gives you only 4 bytes of memory instead of the actual size required by your struct.

```
black = malloc(sizeof(*black));
```

When allocating memory for a pointer, you need to allocate memory for the thing being pointed at, **not** the type of the pointer.  If you simply write `sizeof(*black)` as shown, you will always get the right type, even if the type of `black` changes.

Comment: this way is also valid and more clear, IMHO: 
black = malloc(sizeof(struct black));

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, it seems that you're using an additional level of pointer indirection, and that's causing the segfault. When you malloc memory, it's a pointer to the object, not a pointer to a pointer to an object. So you'll have:

```
img = (struct image *)malloc(sizeof(struct image))
img->o = 0
```

Comment: You need not (and should not) cast the return value of malloc() in C.

Answer (score 1):

JaredPar has the right answer, but if you get a segfault, the first thing to do is run the program under valgrind.  It is a huge help for dealing with problems like this.

BTW, I've wasted days on that exact bug.  Be happy you ran into it early in your C programming career and will always watch out for it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Oops, the code was cut off; I forgot to escape a less-than sign. Here it is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct color {
    unsigned char r, g, b;
};
struct image {
    int w, h/*, o*/;
    struct color **data;
};
int main() {
    // Declarations
    int x, y;
    struct color *black;
    struct image *img;
    // Set up color black
    black = (struct color *) malloc(sizeof(struct color *));
    black->r = 0;
    black->g = 0;
    black->b = 0;
    // Set up image img
    img = (struct image *) malloc(sizeof(struct image *));
    img->w = 1;
    img->h = 1;
    /*img->o = 0;*/
    img->data = (struct color **) malloc(img->h * sizeof(struct color *));
    for (y = 0; y < img->h; y++) {
        img->data[y] = (struct color *) malloc(img->w * sizeof(struct color));
    }
    // Fill in img with black
    for (x = 0; x < img->w; x++) {
        for (y = 0; y < img->h; y++) {
            img->data[y][x].r = black->r;
            img->data[y][x].g = black->g;
            img->data[y][x].b = black->b;
        }
    }
    // Free black
    free(black);
    // Free img
    for (y = 0; y < img->h; y++)
        free(img->data[y]);
    free(img->data);
    free(img);
    // Return
    return 0;
}
```